# How to create a button style and call it without using .buttonStyle?

Tags: button, swiftui

I have created a button style to customize a button. Something like this:

```
struct BlueButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding()
            .background(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.5))
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}
```

To use this, I have to call it like this and it is working fine.

```
.buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle(... my parameters))
```

NOTE: in my case I am passing parameters to it.

But Instead, I would like to call it like this

```
.blueButtonStyle(... my parameters)
```

If that was a regular view modifier, I would do this:

```
extension View {
  func blueButtonStyle(... my parameters) -> some View {
    self.modifier(BlueButtonStyle(... my parameters)
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to use

```
.blueButtonStyle(... my parameters)
```

I get

```
Value of type 'Button<some View>' has no member 'blueButtonStyle'
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
extension View {
  func blueButtonStyle(... my parameters) -> some View {
    self.modifier(BlueButtonStyle(... my parameters)
}
```

with

```
extension View {
  func blueButtonStyle(... my parameters) -> some View {
    self.buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle(... my parameters)
}
```